Whenever I am maximizing the subwindow in MDI in Pyqt5 the minimize, maximize and close buttons gets hidden in the extreme right top corner
Inside the method, a new QMdiSubWindow object is created, and its content is set to windowRef. The title of the sub-window is set to subWindowTitle. The sub-window is also set to be deleted when it is closed, and its window flags are set to include minimize, maximize, and close buttons. Finally, the sub-window is added to the MDI area and displayed, but setWindowFlags is not working in my code.
def subWindowCreation(self, windowRef, subWindowTitle):
        try:
            sub_window = QMdiSubWindow ()
            sub_window.setWidget (windowRef)
            sub_window.resize (windowRef.width (), windowRef.height ())
            sub_window.setWindowTitle (subWindowTitle)
            sub_window.setAttribute (Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            sub_window.setWindowFlags (Qt.Window | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
            print(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint,Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint,Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
            self.ui.mdiMainWindow.addSubWindow (sub_window)
            sub_window.show ()
        except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.about (self, 'Exception', 'Error: "{}"'.format (e))


That's how MDI areas have always worked historically: a maximized subwindow makes its contents occupy the available MDI space, with the system icon moved on the left of the menu bar and the standard window buttons on the right. If you don't want that, you need to implement a fake maximize function that sets the geometry of the subwindow, but you also need to take care of the possible resizing of the MDI area itself, so that the "maximized" window keeps its size consistent with the available area.

Any working demo or example
